# How to segment clients by using hash from python's hashlib

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I need to divide my clients list from df into equal chunks for both ab test groups (into bins).For example, if I have 10 clients in 1st groups and 12 in the second group, clients list should be devided into groups of 5 clients in each ab test groups.

the toy df and my way to divide clients to equal chunks

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'exp_variant_id'  :  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
'test_control'  :  ['control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'control', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'],
'metric_name'  :  ['order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt', 'order_qnt'],
'metric_value'  :  [234, 1, 3234, 1, 44, 1, 1, 22, 234, 22, 33, 234, 2, 22, 3, 2, 22, 432, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 24, 20, 16, 12, 8, 4, 5, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79],
'user_client_id'  :  [21118, 20905444, 56313312, 10738744, 103594830, 83751548, 93299328, 16483186, 130606918, 48995246, 137653680, 63458228, 6968570, 36369312, 13743160, 10331626, 5928990, 50640476, 58021806, 34024250, 4354098, 32314326, 51335518, 31380850, 3710088, 147258556, 6087272, 11858930, 7993504, 100529398, 70127992, 34863920, 18179366, 10651330, 7390348, 18208032, 63247112, 136361832, 36873330, 64035326, 17854770, 106190670, 85201466, 64841914, 116933396, 11482546, 43565902, 112231512, 150755048, 14561480]})

# getting uniq clients 

experiment_var = df.exp_variant_id.unique()

print(f'uniq clients in the exp {df.user_client_id.nunique()}\n')
              

# for loop for each experiment variant  to get the clients that occurent in each 
for a in experiment_var:
    df_new = df[df['exp_variant_id']== a]
    ids = df_new.user_client_id.unique()
    print(f'uniq clients in the exp variant {df_new.user_client_id.nunique()}\n')
    random.shuffle(ids)
    chunks = [ids[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(ids), 4)]

    for numm, vall in enumerate(chunks,1):
       
        df_bin = df_new[df_new['user_client_id'].isin(vall)].copy()

        df_bin.loc[:, 'bin_id'] = numm
```

It gets the work done but I would love to know how to achieve same result using hashlib.

Appreciate all the help)